# Problem in Start And End Dates using CTE

Tags: sql, sql-server-2005, t-sql, common-table-expression

I have the below input

```
ID  Activity    Date
1   gardening   2011-01-01 00:00:00.000
1   gardening   2011-02-01 00:00:00.000
2   cooking 2011-03-01 00:00:00.000
2   cooking 2011-04-01 00:00:00.000
2   cooking 2011-05-01 00:00:00.000
1   gardening   2011-06-01 00:00:00.000
1   gardening   2011-07-01 00:00:00.000
```

The ddl is as under

```
Declare @t table(ID int,Activity Varchar(50),[Date] DATETIME)
Insert into @t Select 1,'gardening','01/01/2011' union all Select 1,'gardening','02/01/2011' 
union all Select 2,'cooking','03/01/2011' union all Select 2,'cooking','04/01/2011'
union all Select 2,'cooking','05/01/2011' union all Select 1,'gardening','06/01/2011'
union all Select 1,'gardening','07/01/2011' 

select * from @t
```

**Expected output**

```
ID ACTIVITY     INITIAL_DATE  END_DATE 
1  gardening    01/01/2011    02/01/2011 
1  gardening    02/01/2011    06/01/2011 
1  gardening    06/01/2011    07/01/2011 
2  cooking      03/01/2011    04/01/2011 
2  cooking      04/01/2011    05/01/2011
```

So far I have done

```
;with cte as(Select Rn= ROW_NUMBER() Over(order by ID,[Date]),* from @t)
,cte2 as(
Select Rn
,ID,Activity,InitialDate =[Date],EndDate = [Date] 
from cte where Rn =1
union all
Select c1.Rn
,c1.ID,c1.Activity,c1.Date,c1.Date
from cte2 c2
join cte c1
on c1.rn  = c2.Rn+1

)
select ID,Activity,InitialDate,EndDate from cte2
```

but the output is not correct

```
ID  Activity    InitialDate EndDate
1   gardening   2011-01-01 00:00:00.000 2011-01-01 00:00:00.000
1   gardening   2011-02-01 00:00:00.000 2011-02-01 00:00:00.000
1   gardening   2011-06-01 00:00:00.000 2011-06-01 00:00:00.000
1   gardening   2011-07-01 00:00:00.000 2011-07-01 00:00:00.000
2   cooking 2011-03-01 00:00:00.000 2011-03-01 00:00:00.000
2   cooking 2011-04-01 00:00:00.000 2011-04-01 00:00:00.000
2   cooking 2011-05-01 00:00:00.000 2011-05-01 00:00:00.000
```

Help needed

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
;with cte as 
(
  select *,
         row_number() over(partition by ID order by [Date]) as rn
  from @t         
)
select C1.ID,
       C1.Activity,
       C1.[Date] as INITIAL_DATE,
       C2.[Date] as END_DATE
from cte as C1
  inner join cte as C2
    on C1.ID = C2.ID and
       C1.rn + 1 = C2.rn
order by C1.ID, C1.[Date]
```

Comment: Eriksson  good idea :)
i didn't think like this..
thanks to give new option

Comment: @pratik – There is no `lead` function in SQL Server so I guess that is why I think like this :) .

Comment: ohhh k...

i was not aware about corresponding function in sql server.. :)

Answer (score 0):

try this -

in oracle it is giving desired output..
please check for respective sql server function for lead () in oracle database

```
with cte as(Select * from @t) 
(
SELECT * from 
(
SELECT id,activity,
   lead(date) over(partition be id,activity order by date desc) INITIAL_DATE,
   date END_DATE  
from cte 
order by id,activity,date
)
WHERE INITIAL_DATE is not null 
)
```